# How to add a gradle configuration as pom dependency using maven-publish plugin?

Tags: gradle

When the gradle 'maven-publish' plugin generates a pom.xml, how can I instruct it to add a configuration to the dependencies listed in that pom?

In the current *'maven'* plugin, the following line would be used to instruct it to include the 'myCustom' configuration as a compile dependency:

```
conf2ScopeMappings.addMapping(1, configurations.myCustom, "compile")
```

I'm effectively looking to get the same functionality with the new *'maven-publish'* plugin

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

configurations {
    myCustom
}

dependencies {
    myCustom 'my:custom-dep:1.0'
}

publishing {
  publications {
    myPublication(MavenPublication) {

    }
 }
}
```

run `gradle generatePomFileForMyPublicationPublication`

current result:

```
<project xsi: ... >
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>id</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>pkg</packaging>
                             <-- need custom-dep dependency here
</project>
```

Comment: As far as I know, the incubating `maven-publish` plugin doesn't support this yet, and you'd have to use the provided XML hook to rewrite the POM (which you'll likely have to do anyway to fix dependency scopes).